# Count new entries day by day

Tags: sql, hive

I would like to count new id's in each day. Saying new, I mean new relative to the day before.
Assume we have a table:

| Date | Id |
| --- | --- |
| 2021-01-01 | 1 |
| 2021-01-02 | 4 |
| 2021-01-02 | 5 |
| 2021-01-02 | 6 |
| 2021-01-03 | 1 |
| 2021-01-03 | 5 |
| 2021-01-03 | 7 |

My desired output, would look like this:

| Date | Count(NewId) |
| --- | --- |
| 2021-01-01 | 1 |
| 2021-01-02 | 3 |
| 2021-01-03 | 2 |

Answer (score 1, accepted):

here is another way, probably the simplest :

```
select t1.Date, count(*) from table t1
where id not in (select id from table t2 where t2.date = t1.date- interval '1 day')
group by t1.Date
```

Comment: I would prefer `exists`, just because when you use `exists` and you find one row matching your criteria, the subquery stops and continue with next record. Not sure that `in` behaves this way.

Comment: That's great. Thank you. I guess there should be: interval '1' day

Answer (score 2):

You can use two levels of aggregation:

```
select date, count(*)
from (select id, min(date) as date
      from t
      group by id
     ) i
group by date
order by date;
```

If by "relative to the day before" you mean that you want to count someone as new whenever they have no record on the previous day, then use `lag()` . . . carefully:

```
select date,
       sum(case when prev_date = date - interval '1' day then 0 else 1 end) 
from (select t.*,
             lag(date) over (partition by id order by date) as prev_date
      from t
     ) t
group by date
order by date;
```

Comment: @eshirvana, yes - this one works relative to all previous days

Comment: Thank you. This is it:)

Comment: @Michał89 . . . I would expect this to be the fastest and most concise way to solve your problem.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this other option could also do the job, but being honest I would prefer the @GordonLinoff answer:

```
select date, count(*)
from your_table t
where not exists (
  select 1 
  from your_table tt
  where tt.Id=t.id
    and tt.date = date_sub(t.date,1)
  )
group by date
```

Comment: This one works relative to all previous days. What I would like to achieve is counting new id's relative only to one day before. Check example

Comment: @Michał89, you were right. I have made a little change in the query to check just the previous date. Bearing in mind that your sample data have days, without hh:mm:ss, a comparison with "=" must work.